# Windows Batch Script - File iteration issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Id like to read input from many files one at a time and process that input before going to the next file. All files have a special name that defines their order of input. It is as follows: ordersheet_a_b_d. I though the following code in a batch file would allow me to read them in the order specified by the for loops, but it doesn't do anything. Can anyone maybe see the mistake? I have the following in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (20, 40, 80) do (
for %%b in (80, 160) do (
for /l %%c in (1,1,3) do (
for /l %%d in (1,1,10) do (
for /l %%e in (1,1,6) do (
for /l %%f in (0,1,6) do ( 
if %%e LSS %%f (
if exist ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d echo "  " %%e %%f >> output.txt
if exist ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d START ThesisVelo.exe distancematrix_%%a.txt ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d %%c %%d %%e %%f >> output.txt
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

Comment: Nice, but you should explain more from your code.

Comment: Well for example, the first file to be read should be ordersheet_20_80_1, the second ordersheet_20_80_2 and so on. Anyway, I think I'm doing something wrong with the %'s or something..

Comment: Without a sample of the directory in which this batch is running, it's blind guessing. HOWEVER - assuming that the target file exists, `%%e` will run from 1-6, and `%%f` from 0-6. With your test, `%%f`=0 or 1 and `%%e`=6 can never enter the `if exist` statements.

Comment: ah you are right, thanks! I don't know much about programming in general, so I'm sorry if I'm leaving out useful information. However I know the .exe works fine, even if %%e never gets reached

Comment: but when i try to input the ordersheets via this batch file, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below achieve the same process of your original code, but it have minor modifications that made the code clearer and show the names of the processed files. Please, note that I don't know what your code is supposed to achieve!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (20  40  80) do (
   for %%b in (80  160) do (
      for /l %%c in (1,1,3) do (
         for /l %%d in (1,1,10) do (
            for /l %%e in (1,1,6) do (
               rem Just process values of %%f greater than %%e
               set /A f=%%e+1
               for /l %%f in (!f!,1,6) do (
                  echo ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d c=%%c, d=%%d, e=%%e, f=%%f
                  if exist ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d (
                     echo "  " %%e %%f >> output.txt
                     START ThesisVelo.exe distancematrix_%%a.txt ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d %%c %%d %%e %%f >> output.txt
                  )
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Some segments of the output:

```
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=2
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=3
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=4
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=5
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=6
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=2, f=3
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=2, f=4
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=2, f=5
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=2, f=6
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=3, f=4
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=3, f=5
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=3, f=6
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=4, f=5
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=4, f=6
ordersheet_20_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_2 c=1, d=2, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_2 c=1, d=2, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_3 c=1, d=3, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_3 c=1, d=3, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_4 c=1, d=4, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_4 c=1, d=4, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_5 c=1, d=5, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_5 c=1, d=5, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_6 c=1, d=6, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_6 c=1, d=6, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_7 c=1, d=7, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_7 c=1, d=7, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_8 c=1, d=8, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_8 c=1, d=8, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_9 c=1, d=9, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_9 c=1, d=9, e=5, f=6

ordersheet_20_80_10 c=1, d=10, e=1, f=2
. . .
ordersheet_20_80_10 c=1, d=10, e=5, f=6


The same block above with c=2 and c=3 until:
ordersheet_20_80_10 c=3, d=10, e=5, f=6



The same whole block above, from:
ordersheet_20_160_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=2
until:
ordersheet_20_160_10 c=3, d=10, e=5, f=6




The same whole block above, from:
ordersheet_40_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=2
until:
ordersheet_40_160_10 c=3, d=10, e=5, f=6



The same, from:
ordersheet_80_80_1 c=1, d=1, e=1, f=2
until:
ordersheet_80_160_10 c=3, d=10, e=5, f=6
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aacini, this is very useful for me! I won't explain in detail but, this code is meant for testing a VRP program for bike sharing systems

Comment: I actually have another problem now. For example, I added the file  ordersheet_20_80_1 to the map containing the .bat and .exe files. However when I execute the .bat file, it seems this line is never true `if exist ordersheet_%%a_%%b_%%d (`. Any ideas?